# How does the Webfilter of Windows Vista's "Parental controls" work?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, proxy, parental-controls

How does the Webfilter of Windows Vista's "Parental controls" work? Is it integrated in IE or a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The controls on Windows 7 disable all other browsers, so it must be IE only.  If Vista is anything like Windows 7 then it is probably the same.  I didn't see any details about it, so I tried installing it.  Wasted a few hours on the whole process.